# Could it be possible to add the integer type to the ECMAScript standard?

Tags: javascript, language-design, ecmascript

In JavaScript, every number you will ever use will always be represented with what C programmer would call a `double`. The official type is I believe `number`. If I recall correctly, that fact was mentioned by Google as a "fundamental" problem with JavaScript and one of the reason why they wanted to have clean break with Dart. Now, I can't help but wonder :

- Can the ECMAScript standard just add that type? Would it be possible to do without breaking existing code?
- Anyway, can't a JIT engine watch the integer usage and generate code that is almost as efficient as using a native integer type, by using integer registers and opcodes?

In effect : Could it be done? *Why should it be done?*

Comment: Javascript 2.0 has that, and more.  http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/js20-1999-02-18/types.html.  Hopefully we can get support in modern browsers in the next few years.

Comment: Question: what does `9999999999999999 % 9` evaluate to? ;)

Comment: @Robert Harvey: maybe support in the next couple of  decades, considering that spec is nearly old enough to drink.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

As for your second point, yes, integer use can be detected. Firefox does it as part of their [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/) feature. It's not entirely straightforward: for example, adding two integers may overflow. That wont happen if the values were added as double. To account for this, every expression that should produce a true 32 bit int is appended with `| 0`, which does nothing except forcing the result to be an int.

Comment: I see. Could it be done non asm.js code though?

Comment: Much like there are JS classes for complex numbers, you could write an __int__ class that has `add(), subtract()` etc. and it does the `| 0` trick.  I suspect somebody has already done this???  Or are you more concerned about performance?